# O que é uma "active autonomous transaction"?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou obtendo esse erro:

> ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back
>   ORA-06512: at "SGR20.CR_PKG", line 289
>
> View program sources of error stack?

Antes que alguém pergunte o erro está dando em um Pacote(PKG) do Oracle e a linha apontada é a do final do código do pacote:

```
END PERSISTIR_CR;
```

**Creio que essa informação não é útil pois só queria saber o que o Oracle chama de "active autonomous transacion", para poder partir para uma investigação do problema.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma transação autonoma no oracle, funciona da seguinte maneira: uma procedure/package/function inicia uma nova transação e efetua commit das alterações efetuadas, sem impactar na transação ativa que a chamou.